# Override child package dependency with specific version

Tags: angular, npm

I have several packages on my application, for example:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "13.4.0",
}
```

The resulting package-lock.json, produced the following

```json
"node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular": {
    ...
    "sass-loader": "12.4.0",
    "semver": "7.3.5",
    ...
},
...
"node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli": {
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "semver": "^7.0.0",
},
```

So, we have multiples of packages `semver` on the package-lock.json that comes from the parent library (build-angular, compiler-cli, and many more). Inside package.json, I don't even have `semver` package as dependency.

My question is how to I override the `semver` package, so that it will use specific package?
I'm looking at adding the `overrides` configuration in package.json

```json
"overrides": {
    "semver": "~7.5.2"
}
```

It seems that there is no impact on it (the package-lock.json is still using various versions of semver). How to resolve it?
There are many other packages (build-angular, compiler-cli, and many more) that depends on semver, how to update all those dependencies at once to specific version?